# Can you freeze Spring Roll Wraps?

Tags: freezing

I have some extra bags of spring roll wraps. Am I able to freeze them and if so how? Also would I be able to freeze them once I make spring rolls. The spring rolls would contain :

- shrimp
- pork
- carrots
- mushrooms
- onions
- eggs
- vermicelli noodles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can freeze either the wrappers or the pre-made rolls and they will work fine. The wrappers I buy are typically frozen.